# Error when predicting breast cancer using logistic regression

Tags: logistic-regression

**Summarize the problem**: Received an error

```
 1 # predict the test dataset
----> 2 yhat = model.predict(X_test)

File c:\Users\nwm2\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\_base.py:425, in LinearClassifierMixin.predict(self, X)
    411 def predict(self, X):
    412     """
    413     Predict class labels for samples in X.
    414 
   (...)
    423         Vector containing the class labels for each sample.
    424     """
--> 425     scores = self.decision_function(X)
    426     if len(scores.shape) == 1:
    427         indices = (scores > 0).astype(int)

File c:\Users\nwm2\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\_base.py:407, in LinearClassifierMixin.decision_function(self, X)
    387 """
    388 Predict confidence scores for samples.
    389 
   (...)
    403     this class would be predicted.
    404 """
...
    118         )
    119 # for object dtype data, we only check for NaNs (GH-13254)
    120 elif X.dtype == np.dtype("object") and not allow_nan:
"ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64')."
```

**Provide details and any research**: Converting breast cancer dataset - categorical data into numbers using feature-engine. Seems to work up to - `yhat = model.predict(X_test)` with above error.

I've tried checking for nans in my dataset but there's none.

Here's the code

````py
# load libraries
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from feature_engine.encoding import OrdinalEncoder
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score

# load dataset
df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jbrownlee/Datasets/master/breast-cancer.csv', header=None)
df.head()

# assign labels to features
names = ['Age', 'Menopause', 'Tumor-Size', 'Inv-Nodes', 'Node-Caps', 'Deg-Malig', 'Breast', 'Breast-Quad', 'Irradiat', 'Class']
df.columns = names

# use a loop to determine which features are categorical and which are numerical
for name in names:
    if name != 'Class':
        if df[name].dtype == 'object':
            print(name, 'is categorical')
        else:
            print(name, 'is numerical')

# print out the number of categorical features
print('Number of categorical features:', len(df.select_dtypes(include=['object'])))

# print out the number of numerical features
print('Number of numerical features:', len(df.select_dtypes(include=['number'])))

# use train test split method from scikit-learn library to seperate dataset into 70% training and 30% test
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df.drop(['Class'], axis=1), df['Class'], test_size=0.3, random_state=1)

# use feature_engine method Ordinal Encoder to convert categorical features to ordinal
encoder = OrdinalEncoder(encoding_method='arbitrary')

#fit the data to the model
encoder.fit(X_train)

# use transform to encode the categories to numbers
X_train = encoder.transform(X_train)
X_test = encoder.transform(X_test)

#check for nans in X_test
print(X_test.isnull().sum())

# Ordinal encode target variable y
label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
label_encoder.fit(y_train)
y_train = label_encoder.transform(y_train)
y_test = label_encoder.transform(y_test)

# check for any nans
print(df.isnull().sum())

# use logistic regression method from scikit-learn library to predict malignancy
model = LogisticRegression()

# fit the model to the training dataset
model.fit(X_train, y_train)

print(X_test.isnull().sum())

X_test = X_test.fillna(X_test.mean())
X_test.isnull().sum()

# predict the test dataset - error happens here!
yhat = model.predict(X_test)**

# print out accuracy score using accuracy_score method from scikit-learn library
accuracy_score = accuracy_score(y_test, yhat)
print('Accuracy: %.2f' % (accuracy_score * 100))
```
````

Comment: With changes above, accuracy_score = accuracy_score(y_test, yhat) -> 
1 # print out accuracy score using accuracy_score method from scikit-learn library
----> 2 accuracy_score = accuracy_score(y_test, yhat)
         3 print('Accuracy: %.2f' % (accuracy_score * 100))
      4 
      5 # use mean absolute error to determine variance from mean, print out the error
      6 print('Mean absolute error: %.2f' % mean_absolute_error(y_test, yhat))

TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not callable

Answer (score 1):

You need to use dropna before train test split.

Xtest has na because it was made from df having na

Comment: Thanks for the tip. As for nans, seems it was generated during the encoding process 'X_test = encoder.transform(X_test)

c:\Users\nwm2\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\feature_engine\encoding\base_encoder.py:238: UserWarning: During the encoding, NaN values were introduced in the feature(s) Inv-Nodes.
  warnings.warn(

Comment: #check for nans in X_test
print(X_test.isnull().sum()) generates nans in Inv-Nodes not sure why

Comment: Used X_test = X_test.fillna(X_test.mean()) to avoid an error msg